# Wargaming Game Center install

Tags: games

I have attemped to install Wargaming Game Centre through Litrus on a few occations.
so far I keep getting an error with the %AppData%
Litrus offers the installation point as: /home/debbie/Games/world-of-tanks
I select: Create application menu short cut
and select install button.
I select Asia from the dropdown menu and press continue button
The installation starts
after a few moments the Wine popup configuring the installation
I get a command exit code 256 and the installation is stopped

```
Warning: /home/debbie/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-7.2-2-x86_64-/bin/win cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message-""
```

Can any one help me understand what is wrong?

below this waring message is a dotted line with this written below

Monitored process exited.
Initial process has exited (return code: 256)
All precesses have quit

OS=
Description:   Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; thus we can only be *vague* and not fully appreciate what you'd expect to see and what you get. Providing clear instructions including what you're running, what instructions you're following, what you entered & output received (copy/pasted) allow us to better understand exactly what's occurring.  Please use {} around pasted detail.

Comment: I have installed Wine installer, but this version of Ubuntu started as, Ubuntu GamePack 20.04, and some updates for Wine were installed.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu Gamepack 20.04 is actually UA Linux; which uses Ubuntu Gamepack for marketing purposes; ie. its from https://ualinux.com/en/ubuntu-gamepack where Ubuntu comes from ubuntu.com*

Comment: Too whom do I share this with ?????

Comment: You're using a Ubuntu *based system* called UA Linux (*it appears as Ubuntu Gamepack only in marketing as few people go looking for UA Linux*), and is on-topic on SE *Unix & Linux* as per my on-topic post.  Only official Ubuntu *flavors* are on-topic here, all of which are downloaded from ubuntu.com being Ubuntu products & built on Ubuntu infrastructure.  Ubuntu has no *Gamepack* product.